# Click mat-checkbox programmatically by getElementById

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to trigger a click event in ngAfterContentInit().

Running the code below, I got the error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
```

Since I use NgFor to print out all the mat-checkbox,

I am afraid I can't use the method - ViewChild to achieve my purpose.

Component:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of NationlityList.NationlityList; let i = index">
  <div *ngIf="i % 6 == 0" class="row">
      <mat-checkbox id="{{'Id'+i}}" *ngIf="i + 0 < NationlityList.NationlityList.length" (change)="onCheckboxChecked($event, NationlityList.NationlityList[i].Nationality)"> {{ NationlityList.NationlityList[i].Nationality }} </mat-checkbox>
      <mat-checkbox id="{{'Id'+(i+1)}}" *ngIf="i + 1 < NationlityList.NationlityList.length" (change)="onCheckboxChecked($event, NationlityList.NationlityList[i+1].Nationality)"> {{ NationlityList.NationlityList[i+1].Nationality }} </mat-checkbox>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
ngAfterContentInit() {
if (this.passedData.SelectedNationlity[0] !== 'All') {
  let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('Id21');
  element.click();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please reproduce an issue in stackblitz

Comment: There are at least a couple ways to do this the "angular" way, [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) and [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview#setup-in-reactive-forms) come to mind. Edit: I'm guessing ViewChild doesn't work because the element is ready on `ngAfterViewInit`.

Comment: @stealththeninja ViewChild is not work for me because I need to trigger the event through dynamic ID. Thanks for your comment~

Comment: Try it in the different life cycle hooks and check it

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
document.getElementById('checkboxID').setAttribute('checked','true')
```